# convert from DMS to Lat Long in C

Tags: c

I have an input file (lets say 10 lines) of coordinate pairs with each line looking something like this:

(1653408W, 503223N) (1651614W, 502806N)

These are Lat Long values given in a DMS format. I want to convert these to a more human friendly format like:
1931259W --> 193d 12m 59s W

I have found a way to use fscanf to traverse every line in the file, but im not sure how to convert the forms.

Comment: Im having trouble printing the DMS value in a human readable way. Im not sure how to convert: 1931259W --> 193d 12m 59s W in C...

Comment: If you use `strtol` (recommended) to convert the string to a number, it will give you a pointer to the end of the number it converts, which will point to the quadrant suffix N, E, W, or S.

Comment: also, if the direction is 'S' then the value must be converted to a negative number.  Similar considerations apply when the direction is 'E'.  BTW:  that value 193 is greater that 180 degrees around the world, so even though the direction is 'W' need to adjust the value to 360-193..  Similar considerations exist for the N/S but the limit is 90 degrees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that your coordinates are given in the format `DDDMMSS`, where `DDD` is an (up to) three-digit number of degrees, `MM` is a two-digit number of minutes and `SS` is a two-digit number of seconds, with no separators between them.

Technically, the "proper" way to parse a format like that would be to split the string into pieces and then convert each piece into an integer separately.  But since you've already managed to read the whole coordinate value into a single integer, as if it were a single decimal number, we can just work with that and extract the degrees, minutes and seconds using simple math:

```
int dddmmss = 1631259;  /* hardcoded input value for testing */

int degrees = dddmmss / 10000;        /* drop the lowest 4 digits */
int minutes = (dddmmss / 100) % 100;  /* drop the lowest 2 digits, then keep the next 2 */
int seconds = dddmmss % 100;          /* just keep the lowest 2 digits */

printf("%03d° %02d' %02d''", degrees, minutes, seconds);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDhToMwEAfwz/IU/8yQwYIymJoY1HchvRtUoSW0qInxnXwGXwzbsZq5eB/aXC/53V3FVSPEPF9KJbqJGA/GktTX7VMklUVfS5Wk@IgufEZEfW8MHlHc7Yry9r4C8g3aeiShiQlSDZPFa91NjL0eYdlYqRps8ugocDMyeyFYOYqtCyct4Twa9QDbMjr95gDcgGQjrfHMQemlmuxBSf4wKWJ/Vf8q5VHJ/KPCC/NSVvzui8E2LLSi0wmDeTLh8@TAX@GswbLtMDptn6zi7Y6@vxBvS1ov53qVhX/IwipZ6JtW0ec8/wA)

Comment: Nice technique, although as someone who does this every day, I found the example very painful to look at, because in the work I do, the longitude is *never* greater than 180!

Comment: also the minutes is never greater than 59 and the seconds is never greater than 59  Therefore, the value after the '%' should not be 100

Comment: @user3629249: `fscanf()` (or `atoi()` or `strtol()` etc.) doesn't know that, though, and just parses the whole `DDDMMSS` digit string as if it were a single decimal number. Which means that, to extract the last two digits from this number, we do need to use `% 100`. Of course you're right that, for valid input, the result of this modulo operation cannot be greater than 59. If you wanted to be extra careful, you could check for that and output an error message if that ever happened.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen,  The example data posted by the OP already shows a degree value of 193.  That means it is over 1/2 way around the world and the actual allowed values are -180... +180 so such values need to be converted

Comment: @user3629249: I suspect that's just a typo in the OP's example. I guess I could change it to, say, 163 degrees in my answer to make it less "painful to look at".